# Codeigniter Active Record Limit

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following code that is working but I want use limit to show only 10 results ordered by ID

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('quotes');
        $this->db->join('quotes_detail', 'quotes_detail.id_rfq = quotes.id_rfq');
        $this->db->join('clients', 'clients.id = quotes.id_company');
        $this->db->limit(10,1);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
```

with the limit code lines, doesn't show anything, but if I remove the line the query works very well.

can anyone help me with this?, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->db->limit(1,10);
```

I think your query did

```
SELECT ...... LIMIT 10,1;
```

It should do

```
SELECT ...... LIMIT 1,10;
```

Comment: not work with `$this->db->limit(1,10);` , thank you.

Comment: May I please see the contents of the database as you query?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->limit(10);    // if you don't have offset
$this->db->limit(10, 0);     // if you have offset value
```

Comment: Adding some context and formatting code would help.

Answer (score 1):

```
this->db->limit(10,1);
```

First parameter is a limit.
The second parameter lets you set a result offset.

If you want to get something by id use:

```
$this->db->where('id', $some_id);
```

or if you have array:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $some_ids_in_array);
```

And if you want to order by id use:

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'desc'); // or asc
```